# CCAH hands on experience without having to take the class

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I want to take/prepare for the Cloudera Certified Administrator for Apache Hadoop (CCAH) lab and I have a few books (any suggestions of reading material would be amazing) but was curious if anyone had any advise on how to get the best hands on experience for training with this certification

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best preparation cfro CCAH  is taking the course: Cloudera Administrator Training for Apache Hadoop.
In this education You will have experience almost all Hadoop environment projects, you will be able to establish and manage CDH.
And you will get real time exercises.

I found this education very efficient.
But to take CCAH, also you need to read at least Hadoop Operations by Eric Sammer.
And of course Hadoop The Definitive Guide by Tom White.